# How to export data queried from nested loop soql query

Tags: soql, data-export, workbench, nested

I need to export data by using nested loop query.Both workbench and data loader does not allow to export data queried from nested loop.Is there any way to export nested loop queried data.

Comment: What do you mean? You need to elaborate the scenario to get proper help

Comment: create a report with the same SOQL clauses and you should be able to export from there...

Comment: Yeah pmvsdt ..I have already exported by creating reports.Anyways thanks for your answer.

Comment: The Salesforce inspector chrome/FF plugin has soql export capacity.  Have not tried complex queries but might be worth a go, see  https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/salesforce-inspector/aodjmnfhjibkcdimpodiifdjnnncaafh?hl=en